# Modifying nested arrays in ruby one key at a time, with similar keys at different levels

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

```
 :one => 'val',
    :two => 'http://www.sweeeet.com',
    :three => {
        :four => {
            :three => 'another value'
        }
    },
```

Given the hash above, i want to modify it so that there is a new array with each changed value, ie

:one might become 'a' but everything else is the same, then :two might become 'a' but everything is the same

I can do this so far, but the problem is when it comes to :three which is present in two different levels (i know..)

ideally i'd like two seperate hashes generated in this case, where both the top-level :three and the nested one are changed to 'a', but given the choice the lower-level one should be the one changed

My code so far is below:

```
def generate_hashes hash, text

  hash.each do |k,v|
  # If v is nil, an array is being iterated and the value is k.
  # If v is not nil, a hash is being iterated and the value is v.

  value = v || k

  if value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      p "#{value} is a hash"
    end
    puts "evaluating: #{value} recursively..."
    generate_hashes(value, text)
  else
    # MODIFY HERE! Look for what you want to find in the hash here
    # if v is nil, just display the array value
    newhash=get_original_hash
    newhashtemp=hash.clone

    newhashtemp[k]=text
    newhash.merge!(newhashtemp)
    p newhash
    p "============="
  end
end
```

obviously the merge works if i don't clone the current passed hash, but then the nested :three stays as 'a' forever for every subsequent generated hash

Comment: If the value of the top-level `:three` is `a`, then there is no nested `:three`. Problem solved.

Comment: nope, this is a sample hash. And if the top-level is 'a' then the api will just reject that, but it'd be nice to test both. preferably have both but if that's not possible then just the lower layer

Comment: I recommend you add desired output. I'm not sure what you mean by 'two separate hashes'

Comment: it's ok I've solved it. the snarky comments notwithstanding thanks for your help anyway.